# How where Python modules installed

Tags: python, unix, pip

CentOs, python2 and python3 were installed

I entered the following command on the command line:

> /usr/bin/python3.4 -m pip install
>
> This results in error:
>
> No module named pip

From my understanding, pip is installed by default.

I note by dates in the directory */usr/lib64/python3.4* that modules were installed.

How were these modules installed? e.g. What would have been the alternative if not using pip.

Why is pip not part of default?

Please note I did not setup this system initially.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos pip has a separate package you have to install.

Call `yum search pip` to see packages like:

```
python-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python packages
python27-python-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python packages
rh-python35-python-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python packages
rh-python36-python-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python packages
```

And install the one related to python you use.

Comment: What methods would have been utilized if not pip?

Comment: _pip_ seems to have a special handling in Centos `python -m pip install` gives me
`/usr/bin/python: pip is a package and cannot be directly executed`. You use it by  `pip install juju`. _pip_ command resides in `/usr/bin/pip`